# can anyone tell me why my program gives me garbage value in answer?

Tags: c++, class, oop

/*there is a class name complex that helps to print the number in the format of complex number but instead of given input it gives garbage or random values in answer*/
#include
using namespace std;

```
// 1 + 4i
// 5 + 8i
// -------
// 6 + 12i

class Complex{
    // int a, b;
    int n1,n2;
    // friend Complex sumComplex(Complex o1, Complex o2);
    public:
        void setNumber(int n1, int n2){
        //     a = n1;
        //     b = n2;
         }

        // Below line means that non member - sumComplex funtion is allowed to do anything with my private parts (members)
        void printNumber(){
            cout<<"Your number is "<<n1<<" + "<<n2<<"i"<<endl;
        }
};

// Complex sumComplex(Complex o1, Complex o2){
//     Complex o3;
//     o3.setNumber((o1.a + o2.a), (o1.b+o2.b))
//     ;
//     return o3;
// }

int main(){
    Complex c1, c2; //sum;
    c1.setNumber(1, 4);
    c1.printNumber();

    c2.setNumber(5, 8);
    c2.printNumber();

    // sum = sumComplex(c1, c2);
    // sum.printNumber();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix those warnings.  I suggest avoiding having your *parameter* names the same as your *member* names, because the name shadowing can cause hard bugs to ferret out.

Comment: FYI, the C++ language has a `complex` type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setNumber` member function currently does nothing because you have only comments inside the member function. You have to set the value of the data members `n1` and `n2` to the passed argument as shown below:

```
void setNumber(int n1, int n2){
     this->n1 = n1;//note this-> used here 
     this->n2 = n2;//note this-> used here
}
```

Also, ideally you **should not name the parameters** to the `setNumber` member function **same as data members**. So the `setNumber` member function should look something like:

```
void setNumber(int a, int b){//parameters names changed to a and b
     n1 = a; //assign value to n1
     n2 = b; //assign value to n2
}
```

Note that you can also use a **constructor** to initialize the data members as shown below:

```
class Complex{
    int n1,n2;
    public:
        void setNumber(int a, int b){
             n1 = a;//this is assignment  
             n2 = b;//this is assignment 
         }
         //parameterize constructor
         Complex(int a, int b): n1(a), n2(b)//uses constructor initialzer list
         {
             
         }
        void printNumber(){
            cout<<"Your number is "<<n1<<" + "<<n2<<"i"<<endl;
        }
};


int main(){
    Complex c1(1,4); //use constructor 
    c1.printNumber();
}
```

Note in the above example, instead of calling the member function `setNumber` we are using the constructor to initialize the data members `n1` and `n2`.